# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum secret cache?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Am using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to save an image to the Photo library. All works fine.

But....after 1st use I'm suffering an allocated piece of RAM which doesn't get released. I think this is an index to each of the images already in the device's library. Can be huge when the user has many images.

I tried wrapping the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum call in a @autoreleasepool block, but no luck.

Any ideas how I can get this RAM back?

Many thanks
-Andrew